# paraFoam command in Ubuntu gives me warnings and errors

Tags: error-handling, paraview, openfoam

I am new to openFoam and wanted to see how it could model flow around a baffle in a square duct.  1
I was watching the following video on how to install openFoam https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMoFaZcPifM.  Everything worked just fine until I got to the command to type "paraFoam"
The command gave me the following response:

[Start of the generated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn9eh.png)

which continued and then it ended showed me this:
[End of the generated code and start of other statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zU8x.png)

I tried modifying the bashrc file per some online instructions.
But I still get the same error

[bashrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOA7o.png)